# Implementing an async task in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a View controller where I have a button which brings up the front camera. The user then takes a photo, the camera controller is dismissed and I show the picture taken in an Image View in the View Controller. Now, I start uploading the server to Amazon S3.

It does take some time for the uploading to complete and the user has to wait for that time before moving to the next view.

I would ideally like to move the user to the next view and let the uploading complete in the background. Is there some way I could do this uploading task in the background ? I know their is something called `dispatch_queue` which could be used to do this but I am not sure how. If I put the uploading code inside a queue in the view controller file and then move to the next view controller, will not the reference of the previous one be lost.

**EDIT**

I tried doing the following -

1. Making a new class which would be responsible for uploading to Amazon S3.
2. This new class is a delegate to `AmazonServiceRequest` which should be called when the uploading to Amazon S3 is complete.
3. On completion uploading to S3, I make a call to my server to save the URL in the database.
4. I make an object of this class inside the queue block like follows -

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    RIDEUploadPhotoService *uploadPhotoServiceObj = [[RIDEUploadPhotoService alloc] init;
    [uploadPhotoServiceObj uploadAndSaveImage:imageToSave];
});
```

It seems to me that the control never comes inside the request complete which should get called when uploading to Amazon S3 is complete.

Comment: tldr; what have you tried?

Comment: You probably don't want your networking operation logic in a view controller anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of the asynchronous upload-mechanisms of NSURLConnection/NSURLSession, so you don't have to mess around with background threads. For example:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:...];

// modern way: NSURLSession
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileURL completionHandler:...];
[uploadTask resume];

// old way: NSURLConnection 
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:...];

// another old way: synchronous NSURLRequest executed in a background queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
});
```

Comment: It's not just one network connection. I am first uploading to Amazon S3 using their SDK which implements a delegate-style - on completion of upload, the request to my server is done. Please have a look at my updated question. Thanks for help!

Comment: Okay... So your problem is that the AmazonServiceRequestDelegate methods aren't called? Or does your RIDEUploadPhotoService just doesn't seem to send a request to your server?

Comment: The AmazonServiceRequestDelegate method is not being called.

Comment: So just to eliminate the easy ones...
a) did you set the .delegate
b) did you check that your delegate isn't dealloced too early? (Override dealloc() and set a breakpoint)
c) is it just the request:didCompleteWithResponse: that isn't called or are the other delegate-methods also not being called?

Comment: I have set .delegate. How can I check if the delegate isn't deallocated? I have just implemented the request:didCompleteWithResponse. The error delegate isn't being called either.

Answer (score 0):

No. The reference will not be lost.

You can use `- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg` to perform the method `aSelector` in the background. If you have any delegates after the completion of the task, they will still be called.

Comment: The reference *could* be lost

Comment: And thus, I stand corrected. :)
It _could_ be lost. :)

Comment: So if the reference is lost, the delegates will not be called. How can I make sure they are called? That is what I am trying to do.